# Latest AMI ID in a given Region using a set of filters

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ami

I am trying to run the code in the below, however I have errors while executing, could you please advise on the changes.

[latest-ami](https://github.com/bwood/latest-ami/blob/master/latest-ami.py)

```
    [ec2-user@ip-XXXXXXXX ~]$ python latest-ami.py us-west-2
{u'Images': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': '01ef1583-e7bc-4279-9081-28cbf9345f7c', 'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Wed, 01 Aug 2018 12:00:01 GMT', 'content-length': '219', 'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'server': 'AmazonEC2'}}}
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-19-75 ~]$ python latest-ami.py us-west-1
{u'Images': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': 'e61cdeb3-e44b-4e4e-bf4e-ed4681529757', 'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Wed, 01 Aug 2018 12:06:00 GMT', 'content-length': '219', 'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'server': 'AmazonEC2'}}}
[ec2-user@ip-XXXXXXXXXXX ~]$
```

I am expecting something like below as the output:

```
$ latest-ami.py us-west-2
ami-b04e92d0
```

My code now looks like below the last three lines from the original [latest-ami](https://github.com/bwood/latest-ami/blob/master/latest-ami.py)

```
source_image = newest_image(response['Images'])
#print(source_image['ImageId'])
print(response)
```

filters are like below:

```
filters = [ {
        'Name': 'name',
        'Values': ['amzn-ami-hvm-*']
    },{
        'Name': 'description',
        'Values': ['Amazon Linux AMI*']
    },{
        'Name': 'architecture',
        'Values': ['x86_64']
    },{
        'Name': 'owner-alias',
        'Values': ['amazon']
    },{
        'Name': 'owner-id',
        'Values': ['000000000000']
    },{
        'Name': 'state',
        'Values': ['available']
    },{
        'Name': 'root-device-type',
        'Values': ['ebs']
    },{
        'Name': 'virtualization-type',
        'Values': ['hvm']
    },{
        'Name': 'hypervisor',
        'Values': ['xen']
    },{
        'Name': 'image-type',
        'Values': ['machine']
    } ]

response = client.describe_images(Owners=['amazon'], Filters=filters)
```

Comment: My friend "I have many errors" does not help anyone. Describe what error you are getting and maybe someone can help you out.

Comment: File "test2", line 8, in <module>
    region = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Jack Update the question accordingly

Comment: The error indicates that the script is executing and expecting a command line argument. Did u pass one?

Comment: yes, After I have changed sys.argv[1] to sys.argv[0], I have a different error like `botocore.vendored.requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ec2.latest-ami.py.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 503 Service Unavailable',)))`

Comment: In the command line I am passing `python latest-ami.py`

Comment: edited the question with the exact error

Comment: @Jack sys.argv[0] is the name of the script.

Comment: Your script is looking for a input for region variable. So Try triggering this something like this `python latest-ami.py us-east-1`. us-east-1 is a sample region i took. Replace this with the region u are looking for.

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: given the output in the question `python latest-ami.py us-west-2`

Comment: @RhythemAggarwal where did i make a mistake

Comment: Let me update my answer below

Comment: Wait,it looks like there is no response. Are you selecting the correct filters to get the correct AMI ID ? `u'Images': []` means there are no AMIs in that filter set

Comment: @RhythemAggarwal, added filters in the question, i believe they are correct.

Comment: @Jack just out of curiosity, can u try doing something like `response = client.describe_images(Owners=['amazon'])` with no filters, and comment here what is the response you get?

Comment: @RhythemAggarwal, after a minute of delay below is an extract of the output: `[ec2-user@ip-XXXXXXXX ~]$ python nofilters-latest-ami.py us-west-2`  `{u'Images': [{u'VirtualizationType': 'paravirtual', u'Hypervisor': 'xen', u'ImageOwnerAlias': 'amazon', u'ImageId': 'aki-30fd7000', u'State': 'available', u'BlockDeviceMappings': [], u'Architecture': 'i386', u'ImageLocation': 'ec2-pub`

Comment: @RhythemAggarwal, after a minute of delay below is an extract of the output: `[ec2-user@ip-XXXXXXXX ~]$ python nofilters-latest-ami.py us-west-2`  `{u'Images': [{u'VirtualizationType': 'paravirtual', u'Hypervisor': 'xen', u'ImageOwnerAlias': 'amazon', u'ImageId': 'aki-30fd7000', u'State': 'available', u'BlockDeviceMappings': [], u'Architecture': 'i386', u'ImageLocation': 'ec2-public-images-us-west-2/vmlinuz-2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen.i686.aki.manifest.xml', u'RootDeviceType': 'instance-store', u'OwnerId': '137112412989', u'CreationDate': '2011-09-30T18:13:52.000Z', u'Public': True, u'ImageTyp`

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: @RhythemAggarwal, yes I believe the filters are correct and they are to fetch the AMI of the Latest AMI ID in a given Region using a set of filters

Comment: @Jack i updated my answer below to print the AMI ID. Check below in answers and accept it if it worked for you

Comment: When ran with filters `[ec2-user@ip-XXXXXXXX ~]$ python latest-ami.py us-east-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "latest-ami.py", line 60, in <module>
    print(source_image['ImageId'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` And when ran without filters `[ec2-user@ip-XXXXXXX ~]$ python nofilters-latest-ami.py us-west-2
ami-0e90ca76`

Comment: Looks great, when I ran without filters, it is giving the AMI ID.. looks like the filter values are messed up

Comment: Issue has been solved, closing this thread. Thanks @RhythemAggarwal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is looking for a parameter value from command line when you execute the script.

Line 8:
`region = sys.argv[1]`

`sys.argv` stores the command line values provided during the script run along with script name.

`sys.argv[0]` : Script name

`sys.argv[1]`:  First command line value

Try running your code like this: `python latest-ami.py us-east-1`

Depending on what region u want to run your code on change the value i provided for region.

To get the image id: `print(source_image['ImageId'])` add this command to your code

Comment: Perfect thanks @RhythemAggarwal, I now have a null error

Comment: I am not sure about what region to choose. Did us-east-1 work for you?

Comment: well perfect!! Close the question if you problem is solved :)

Comment: Thanks @RhythemAggarwal, should I open a new thread for new error, or could we continue on this one

Comment: Edit your question with the new error if it is for the same code

Comment: Thanks @RhythemAggarwal, edited my question. I am now not getting the expected output