# AWS CloudFormation Examples - where do AMI ids come from?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to create an AutoScaling Group using CloudFormation, based on the [official example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/example-templates-autoscaling.html). However, when trying to look up the AMI ids of the config in the console, I cannot find the one corresponding to my region (eu-central-1, ami-0233214e13e500f77).

Where do these ids come from? How can I find the correct ones?

Comment: look for this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51611411/get-latest-ami-id-for-aws-instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AMIs published and updated by AWS or AMIs from the public / marketplace. You can also start with one of these AMIs as a base, customize it, and then create your own AMI.

The AWS-managed AMIs are assigned a new AMI ID with each update. This is why you may occasionally see an AMI ID that is no longer available in examples or documentation.

The latest Amazon Linux and MS Windows AMIs are here:

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/

https://aws.amazon.com/windows/resources/amis/

You can also find latest versions of these AMIs programmatically:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/query-for-the-latest-amazon-linux-ami-ids-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/

Comment: for my usecase, this command provide the necessary information: "aws ssm get-parameters --names /aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2 --region eu-central-1"